# MySQL password not working from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is really strange, for my user `root` I've set the `password` to:

```
roboasd231
```

I can access the MySQL server from `Sequel Pro` just fine, however when i try to login from `PHP` using the exact same details i get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**This is my php code:**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","roboasd231");
if (!$con)
{
die('Cant connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Screen of my `users` table in `mysql` db
[image]

Comment: Please provide us the PHP code you're trying to connect with

Comment: Okay, it seems to be okay for me. (but you should use mysqli in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mosto likely need to enable root access from a remote workstation ...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'root'@'%'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'roboasd231';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'roboasd231';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If the problem is connecting from localhost is because '%' doesn't include localhost access, try to use the net interface IP, for example (192.168.1.1 or whatever else you have).
Otherwise you can add the granting even to localhost, as showed above in the code section of this answer.

Comment: I've got `host` in my `mysql` db in the `users` table set to `%`

Comment: He’s trying to access MySQL from localhost.